# Multi-member governance tools for resources

Tags: ethereum, kaleido

For a consortium with multiple enterprise parties operating a permissioned blockchain, how does governance of the shared infrastructure work with Kaleido?

I assume that one party can launch the blockchain platform (with a fixed set of nodes), invite members, give invited members limited capabilities to manage the shared resources (e.g. they can set up private channels and invite other members, and perhaps add/remove their own nodes/peers?).

Does the party who launches the blockchain consortium instance have more "powers" than invited members (e.g. which AWS region to deploy to)?

Can an invited member add more peers or remote nodes than the rest of the consortium, and then perform something like a 51% attack?

Can payments be split between consortium members?

The encrypted storage: how is this governed between multiple members of a consortium?

I would appreciate any feedback.

Kind Regards,
Zaid

Answer (score 0):

> Does the party who launches the blockchain consortium instance have more "powers" than invited members (e.g. which AWS region to deploy to)?

In the current open beta functionality, Kaleido does exposed the ability for the original creator of a consortium/environment to delete it. Including all nodes owned by all members. This is a convenience feature for PoC stage consortium. Please drop support@kaleido.io an email note directly if you are at a stage with a project where you need to discuss a fully decentralized governance model where this ability is removed.

> Can an invited member add more peers or remote nodes than the rest of the consortium, and then perform something like a 51% attack?

Each consensus algorithm has different byzantine fault tolerance characteristics, and you can read about them here:
https://kaleido.io/consensus-algorithms-poa-ibft-or-raft/

In the current open beta, members invited/permissioned into the private chain are able to add multiple nodes that participate in forming consensus (Clique signers / IBFT validators). Again please contact Kaledio if you have specific requirements in this area.

> Can payments be split between consortium members?

Kaleido is not currently charging for the open beta. However, the ownership model of the Kaleido cloud resources, is that each Kaleido organization owns its own nodes. Each member running nodes in a Kaleido private chain has the control over the lifecycle and operations of their own nodes. As such, it would follow that each participant would pay for their own nodes in such a model.

> The encrypted storage: how is this governed between multiple members of a consortium?

The Kaleido tenancy model is described here:

https://docs.kaleido.io/getting-started/overview/kaleido-tenancy-model/

A further option for encryption of sensitive key materials, is to use use per-tenant master encryption keys stored outside of the Kaleido platform in the AWS Key Management Service (KMS):

https://kaleido.io/why-your-keys-are-safe-in-kaleido/

If you are interested in further details of the virtualization technologies Kaleido uses to dedicate isolated storage to each node, please reach out directly to support.

Many thanks for your questions, and I hope this response gives some additional clarity on the features available in the Kaleido open beta.
Please do reach out to support@kaleido.io directly if you'd like to learn more.

Regards, Peter